# Managing transactional email unsubscribes from Sendgrid

Tags: email, sendgrid

My app sends different transactional emails (using Sendgrid) for different events:

- Somebody follows you
- Somebody likes your picture
- Somebody shared your picture
- etc...

User A only wants to know when people follow her. User B only wants to know when people like or share his picture. User C wants all the emails.

Is there any way to manage the subscriptions to these different transactional emails using Sendgrid? Is there some kind of 'category' email subscription functionality?

If not I'm guessing I'll have to store this locally in the database.

Comment: SendGrid offers this functionality now. See my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not something SendGrid currently supports. Sorry! Stay tuned though ;)

Update: you can now use [Advanced Suppression Manager](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/advanced_suppression_manager.html) for this